# How do I add queue on my music bot using Discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots, background-music

This is my play command for my music bot

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'p',
    description: 'Joins and plays a video from youtube',
    async execute(message, args) {
        const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;
 
        if (!voiceChannel) return message.channel.send('You need to be in a channel to execute this command!');
        const permissions = voiceChannel.permissionsFor(message.client.user);
        if (!permissions.has('CONNECT')) return message.channel.send('You dont have the correct permissins');
        if (!permissions.has('SPEAK')) return message.channel.send('You dont have the correct permissins');
        if (!args.length) return message.channel.send('You need to send the second argument!');
 
        const validURL = (str) =>{
            var regex = /(http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%!\-\/]))?/;
            if(!regex.test(str)){
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
 
        if(validURL(args[0])){
 
            const  connection = await voiceChannel.join();
            const stream  = ytdl(args[0], {filter: 'audioonly'});
 
            connection.play(stream, {seek: 0, volume: 1})
            .on('finish', () =>{
                voiceChannel.leave();
                message.channel.send('leaving channel');
            });
 
            await message.reply(`:thumbsup: Now Playing ***Your Link!***`)
 
            return
        }
 
        
        const  connection = await voiceChannel.join();
 
        const videoFinder = async (query) => {
            const videoResult = await ytSearch(query);
 
            return (videoResult.videos.length > 1) ? videoResult.videos[0] : null;
 
        }
 
        const video = await videoFinder(args.join(' '));
 
        if(video){
            const stream  = ytdl(video.url, {filter: 'audioonly'});
            connection.play(stream, {seek: 0, volume: 1})
            .on('finish', () =>{
                voiceChannel.leave();
            });
 
            await message.reply(`:thumbsup: Now Playing ***${video.title}***`)
        } else {
            message.channel.send('No video results found');
        }
    }
}
```

What does this do is `!p *name of the song/link*` and than he joins and play, but I can't do two songs. And than when first finishes, second plays.

I want to add queue system and skip command. Could you please help me adding a queue and skip system?

Comment: You can make a Map() and then add your songs to the map, then once you are done with a song you .shift() the map to the next song. By this logic, you can also make a queue to be used across all servers. I also made a music bot recently, and here is my code: https://github.com/QuaverMaster/MainCode/blob/main/NodeJS%20v14/index.js if you want a reference

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but I need command in my p.js not in index.js because I have more commands than just a music. If you could show me how I can add queue on this code I will appreciate it. Thanks 

Comment: in a nutshell you make a global Map() which stores your songs. If you want to add a song, you push it to the end of the Map(); that's your queue. If you want to skip a song, then you remove that song from the Map(). That's the general idea which is shown in my code